# Microsoft Graph API - Not able to send mail with attachment

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph 5.17 version in our C# code. Below is the snippet:

```
string tenantId = "";
string clientId = "";
string clientSecret = "";
string sMailboxUserObjectId = "";

var message = new Message();
List<Recipient> recLst = new List<Recipient>();
List<string> ToLst = new List<string>();
ToLst.Add("someone@gmail.com");
foreach (var recipient in ToLst)
{
Recipient recObj = new Recipient();
EmailAddress emailObj = new EmailAddress();
emailObj.Address = recipient;
recObj.EmailAddress = emailObj;
recLst.Add(recObj);
}
message.ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>(recLst);

message.Body = new ItemBody
{
//ContentType = BodyType.Html,
Content = "Test mail, please ignore"
};

message.Subject = "Test Mail. ";
var att1 = new MG.Models.Attachment
{
Name = "PoweredOffMachines_2023_7_18_9.csv",
ContentType = "text/csv",
OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
Id = "PoweredOffMachines_2023_7_18_9",  
};

message.Attachments = new List<MG.Models.Attachment>();
message.HasAttachments = true;
message.Attachments.Add(att1);

var saveToSentItems = false;

SendMailPostRequestBody sendMailReqBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody();
sendMailReqBody.Message = message;
sendMailReqBody.SaveToSentItems = saveToSentItems;

try
{
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new MG.GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    await graphClient
        .Users[sMailboxUserObjectId]
        .SendMail
        .PostAsync(sendMailReqBody);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
return "Failure";
}
```

Able to send mail using above code without file attachment. If attachment is added, below error is shown:
"Exception of type Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError was thrown. "

Please help if anybody have idea about this... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the FileAttachment type and set the contentBytes with the contents of your file and you also shouldn't have to set message.HasAttachments = true; (it should be readonly). eg something like

```
        var message = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message
        {
            Subject = "draft Messages",
        };
        message.Body = new ItemBody
        {
            //ContentType = BodyType.Html,
            Content = "Test mail, please ignore"
        };

        List<Recipient> recLst = new List<Recipient>();
        List<string> ToLst = new List<string>();
        ToLst.Add("user@domain.com");
        foreach (var emailRecipient in ToLst)
        {
            Recipient recObj = new Recipient();
            EmailAddress emailObj = new EmailAddress();
            emailObj.Address = emailRecipient;
            recObj.EmailAddress = emailObj;
            recLst.Add(recObj);
        }
        message.ToRecipients = recLst;
        byte[] attacmentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(attachmentDetails.FullName);
        message.Attachments = new List<Attachment>
        {
            new FileAttachment
            {
                Name = "PoweredOffMachines_2023_7_18_9.csv",
                ContentType = "text/csv",
                ContentBytes = attacmentBytes
            }
        };
        var saveToSentItems = false;
        SendMailPostRequestBody sendMailReqBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody();
        sendMailReqBody.Message = message;
        sendMailReqBody.SaveToSentItems = saveToSentItems;
```

Comment: Hi Glen, tried with your suggestion. It's working fine. Thank you.

Comment: you should pick the √ beside the answer which helped solve your issue to mark the solution and it would help others who has similar questions.. thank you @VenkatPraveen